# How to write Unit Test for Hybris DAO Implementation

Tags: sql, unit-testing, testing, sap-commerce-cloud

I am new with unit test and I am trying to test this method, but it did not manage to capture the query of the method, I only managed to get it to enter an exception but not to take the query and return it.
Is there a way to return "result.getResult().get(0)" in the unit test?

Thanks

```
 @Override
    public HouseModel findByCode(String code) {
        var sQuery = "SELECT {h:pk} FROM {House as h} WHERE {h:id} = ?id ";
        var query = new FlexibleSearchQuery(sQuery);
        query.addQueryParameter("id", Objects.requireNonNullElse(code, ""));
        SearchResult<HouseModel> result = flexibleSearchService.search(query);
        return result.getResult().get(0);
    }
```

Code Test:

```
@Test
    public void testFindByCode() {

        when(flexibleSearchService.search((FlexibleSearchQuery) any())).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("test"));
        RuntimeException exception = new RuntimeException();
        try {
            var result2 = houseDAOImpl.findByCode("testcode");

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            exception = e;
        }
        boolean shouldtrue = exception.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("test");
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        System.out.println(shouldtrue);
        assertTrue(shouldtrue);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hybris supports TransactionTest incase of interaction with db.

```
public class HouseDAOImpTest extends HybrisJUnit4TransactionalTest
{

    private TypeService typeService;
    private ModelService modelService;
    private DeeplinkUrlDao dao;
    private List<HouseModel> createdRules;

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        createdRules = createHouses();
        houseDAOImpl = (HouseFinderDao) Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("houseFinderDao");
    }

    
    @Test
    public void testFindByCode()
    {
        

        final HouseModel hm = houseDAOImpl.findByCode("testcode");
        assertThat(hm.getCode(), is(equalTo(""testcode""));

    }

    

    private ModelService getModelService()
    {
        if (modelService == null)
        {
            modelService = (ModelService) Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("modelService");
        }
        return modelService;
    }

    private TypeService getTypeService()
    {
        if (typeService == null)
        {
            typeService = (TypeService) Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("typeService");
        }
        return typeService;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the Houses.
     */
    private List<HouseModel> createHouses()
    {
        final List<HouseModel> result = new ArrayList<HouseModel>();

        final HouseModel houseModel1 = getModelService().create(HouseModel.class);
        houseModel.setCode("testcode");
        
        modelService.save(houseModel1);

        
     // create other houses model and follow previous steps

        result.add(houseModel1);
        result.add(houseModel2);
        result.add(houseModel3);

        return result;
    }

}
```